# Solspace-Freeform Pro - Leave Non-Required Select Menu Empty?

Tags: solspace-freeform

Select menus left empty by the visitor are having values added to them when updated in the CP because FreeForm is showing the first item in a menu's list by default, even though that's not the data in the database.

Once the form is updated, that default item from the top of the list gets added to the data.

For example, the default list of States (which is not a required field in our form) displays "Alabama" by default at: /cp/addons/settings/freeform/edit_entry&form_id=#&entry_id=#

So we can't update this entry without updating Alabama, in the database, even though our user left it blank.

Short of adding "No Selection" as value to all select fields left blank, what is the intent? How should this be working? Should I be pushing a non-breaking space into the value of a nonselected menu?

Is this just a bug?

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Why to not use first select option as '--'.

Comment: These may help: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12983/setting-blank-value-for-first-option-for-dynamic-freeform-select-load-from-chan and http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/25709/freeform-pro-composer-state-and-country-field-type-how-to-show-unselected and http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions/topics/30384

Comment: Huge help. Thank you. Looks like the assumption was that the state and country fields would always be required. http://www.imdb.com/videoplayer/vi2012938521?ref_=tt_pv_vi_aiv_1